# Mac OS X programmig intro

Tags: macos, programming-languages

I have been using Mac for a while and I am a senior CS major. I want to start making apps for Mac however I dont know where to start. Currently I know java, c++ , c , python as my main languages. Do I need to learn another language like objective-c ? Can anyone point me to a place to start ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the first two things you will need to do is learn how to use Xcode and then you will need to learn Objective-C.

To learn how to use Xcode, I would start with the [Xcode Workspace Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeWorkspace/000-Introduction/Introduction.html)

To learn Objective-C, Apple has a great, free book - [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/ObjC.pdf). The one aspect of Objective-C which makes it easier to learn for many is that it is a true superset of C (C++, for example, is not). If you already know C, Objective-C just adds a little bit to support objects.

Then, I would pick up a copy of Cocoa(R) Programming for Mac(R) OS X (3rd Edition) by Aaron Pablo Hillegass. This book is the standard for starting out to learn Cocoa and build real Mac applications.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to learn objective-c. [Start here](http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should learn Objective-C. While there are other ways to create applications for MacOS X, the Cocoa framework is the best supported and the one to know going forward. Given that you already know several other C-based languages, picking up Objective-C won't be all that difficult. You'll spend much more time learning to use the framework properly than learning the actual language. I'd suggest picking up a book to get you started, and also get familiar with the Cocoa documentation.

Answer (score 0):

actually it's for iOS development but they provide also and good introduction into --> [Objective-C Intro](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=395605774)

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C is the official language to use when writing applications for the Mac, although since it's a superset of C, you can also use C code in your app.

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/index.html#topic=Guides&section=Resource+Types) is a good starting point.